# how to connect oracle database on dbeaver-ce on linux

Tags: oracle, dbeaver

i'm unable to connect to oracle database on my ubuntu 22.04,it gives the below error

```
  The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
  The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    Connection refused, socket connect lapse 0 ms. /127.0.0.1 1521 0 1 true
    Connection refused, socket connect lapse 0 ms. /127.0.0.1 1521 0 1 true
      Connection refused
      Connection refused
```

Comment: Looks like your listener isn't running; or is listening on a different port or IP address - maybe the host (LAN) IP address not localhost? Or a local firewall is blocking it?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, to solve it just restart the services.
then create new user as

```
/as sysdba
create user NewUserName identified by newPass;
grant dba to NewUserName;
```

I hope that will help you.